# Cargar GridView dependiendo a variable de sesión en ASPX

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Tengo el siguiente código donde manejo variables de sesión, la recibe bien, pero tengo dos `GridView` en esta página, si `tipo ="SeguimientoConsultas"` quisiera que solo se muestre un `GridView` digamos el `GridView1`, para no generar los dos `GridView` si solo ocupo uno.

```
        string tipo = (string)(Session["TipoConsulta"]);
        string value = (string)(Session["Value"]);

        if (tipo == "SeguimientoConsultas")
        {
            lblTitulo.InnerText = "Seguimiento Consultas";
        }
        else if (tipo == "GestionSeguros")
        {
            lblTitulo.InnerText = "Gestión de Seguros";
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Pues sólo ocultalo, me imagino que ya los tienes cargados con datos o aún no?

```
string tipo = (string)(Session["TipoConsulta"]);
string value = (string)(Session["Value"]);
GridView1.Visible = false;
GridView2.Visible = false;
if (tipo == "SeguimientoConsultas")
{
    lblTitulo.InnerText = "Seguimiento Consultas";
    GridView1.Visible = true;
}
else if (tipo == "GestionSeguros")
{
    lblTitulo.InnerText = "Gestión de Seguros";
    GridView2.Visible = true;
}
```

Comment: Gracias, es una buena opción, por que se cumple el objetivo que no se ve, pero para cuestiones de rendimiento ahí pega, ¿Existe la forma de digamos de controlar la carga del grid en un evento?

Comment: puedes poner el código o indicar la manera en que cargas los grids?